# Evaluate foo on `mousemove` but only when `mousedown`

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

**How to evaluate `foo` when mouse is down and moving using core/async?**

Whilst attempting to learn the concepts behind core/async I have worked through the [ClojureScript 101 tutorial](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/11/07/clojurescript-101/)  (but I suspect this question applies to clojure to).

I create a channel where mouse movement events are placed using the following:

```
;; helper to get a channel where a dom event type will be put
(defn listen [el type]
  (let [out (chan)]
     (events/listen el type
       (fn [e] (put! out e)))
    out))

;; create a channel for mouse moves, take the values 
;; and pass them to the console 
(let [moves (listen (dom/getElement "canvas") "mousemove")]
  (go (while true
    (foo (<! moves)))))
```

This works, `foo` is evaluated when the mouse moves. But how can this be done only when the mouse is down?

My first guess would be to use an atom and two new channels for `mousedown` and `mouseup`. Then update atom with the mouse state and test against this in the `go` block. But I suspect this is wrong due to the use of an atom; hence the question.

Comment: I don't see why using an atom would be wrong. You want to react to the state of the mouse (down/up) which is a property that has to have a value always (atom), so you can't represent it with channels (events of pressing up or down at certain times). It looks like a simple solution for what you are doing.

Comment: Good to know that would be a desirable way to handle this. I am going to keep trying to get exposure to core/async. I think I am getting closer with `alt!` on three streams (up, down, move).

Comment: @Joaquin I have an implementation below. Great if you could provide feedback. Especially if there is something better than `(alt! [mouse-move mouse-up] ([v p] [v p]))`

Comment: @Joaquin sorry, please ignore... got it.

Comment: // , Ross, would you mind if I modified the question to allow a plainer answer to @Joaquin's suggestion, below?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, here is the closest I have got. Appears to work.

```
;; Util for create DOM channels
(defn listen [el type]
  "Takes a DOM element and an event type. Returns a channel for the event"
  ;; out is a new channel
  (let [out (chan (sliding-buffer 1))]
    ;; attach an event listener
    (events/listen el type
      ;; the handler/callback of the listener takes the 
      ;; event and put! in on the channel. We are using 
      ;; put because we are not in a go block
      (fn [e] (put! out e)))
    ;; return the channel
    out))

(def canvas-el (dom/getElement "canvas"))

(def mouse-up   (listen canvas-el "mouseup"))
(def mouse-down (listen canvas-el "mousedown"))
(def mouse-move (listen canvas-el "mousemove"))

(go (while true
      (<! mouse-down)
      (loop []
        (let [[v ch] (alts! [mouse-move mouse-up])]
          (when (= ch mouse-move) 
            (do 
              (.log js/console "move" (.-clientX v) (.-clientY v))
              (recur)))))))
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm concerned that you might miss the mouse up event if it happens with a mouse move and the alts chooses the second . I'll take a stab at it later and post another answer, I think we can do something using a control channel to pause / continue the mouse move loop.